# How to display specific field names?

Tags: php, mysql

really really new to PHP and Mysql here and trying to teach myself!
I've used
 `echo mysql_field_name($result, 0)`
to display a certain field name from a table and can change which one by changing the number. 
My question is, how can I echo a list of specific field names eg 2-8 to put them in a html table?

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just call `mysql_field_name` in a loop and increment the number you're passing it?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Ah right, I didn't know about PDO, I'll go through the tutorial and try and figure it out. I think the tutorials I've been learning mysql from must be old!

Answer (score 1):

If you use some library such as PDO or mysqli (which you should be using instead of mysql), and you use options to retrieve each row of data as an associative array, the field names will be the key values for the array.  You can get the field names in this manner without any extra overhead to query separately to get the field names.

Comment: Thank you, someone mentioned PDO and mysqli in another comment, I guess that will be something else for me to learn!

Answer (score 0):

So a few comments...

First, the mysql_ libraries are depreciated in 5.5 and later. If you're new to PHP, I would HIGHLY suggest you learn the [mysqli library](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead and use the object version. My examples will assume you have a mysqli object. There are procedural ways to do the same thing, you would just need to pass your DB connection pointer every time.

So we have some sort of query with a DB connector.

```
$sql = 'Some statement here';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

At this point we have a result. There's a couple of better ways to get data from a table than mysql_field_name. One is fetch_object and the other is fetch_assoc. The difference is that fetch_assoc will give you an associative array and the other will give you an object

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['fieldname'];

$row = $result->fetch_object();
echo $row->fieldname;
```

There are other ways to fetch data but these are the two most common because they are the easiest to understand.

Now, if you don't know the name of your fields you can always use [fetch_fields()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) to get that data.

Comment: This is useful too thank you as I wish to construct the query without knowing the field names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MySqli, you can easily do this using a While loop. If you would like to display in a table, it is really easy to do.

Connect to your data source (if you are using mysql not mysqli, I recommend switching.)

`$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");`

Then you want to run your sql script to get the data:

`$mydata = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mytable");`

This is where the While loop will come into play, to display in a table.

```
echo '<table><tr><th>Field1</th><th>Field2</th></tr>';

//This bascially says while you can fetch data from your database, do the
//the following with the label $mytable.
while($mytable = mysqli_fetch_array($mydata)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$mytable['yourfieldnameinyourdb'].'<td>';
    echo '<td>'.$mytable['your2fieldnameinyourdb'].'</td></tr>'; 
}

echo '</table>';
```

So the complete code would be:

```
<?
// Connect your your DB
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Get your data
$mydata = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mytable");
// Start the table
echo '<table><tr><th>Field1</th><th>Field2</th></tr>';
// Do the loop
while($mytable = mysqli_fetch_array($mydata)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$mytable['yourfieldnameinyourdb'].'<td>';
    echo '<td>'.$mytable['your2fieldnameinyourdb'].'</td></tr>'; 
}
// End your table
echo '</table>';
?>
```

If this didn't quite answer your question, just let me know.

Comment: This is a really good reply and is just what I was trying to do thank you!